# Automated execution of a powershell script on Active Directory, Triggered from a web page

Tags: powershell, web, active-directory, citrix, netscaler

I am proposing an idea for a final year project that is basically a virtual environment. I would be using Citrix XenServer in conjunction with Windows Server 2008 R2 and Citrix netscaler to make the server accessible over the web. I would also be hosting a website on the server that Windows is on.

What I was wondering is, would it be possible to trigger the execution of a script on the server from the web page. So basically a user comes along, goes to my website, registers their details. a csv file is then produced based on the details that are input. Then I was wondering is there a way to trigger the execution of a powershell script that would use the csv file to set up the user in Active directory. The powershell script itself is simple its just how I would get it to run is another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

PowerShell lets us create graphical interfaces with the .NET winforms. With it, we can build front end to manage our scripts. It's a really nice feature, and tools like [AdminScriptEditor](http://www.adminscripteditor.com/) make it pretty easy.

I have found this link for your reference - [PowerShellOnWebPage](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html)

You can tweak/create the script as per your need.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks!